# AS3: manage gap in mx:VBox when I add programmatically component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml, vbox

I've this situation:

A main component where root node is .

In this VBox I explicit the property verticalGap = "0".

In the creation complete, I add a lot of components, in this way:

```
var pnlFirstCmp:PnlFirstCmp = new PnlFirstCmp();
this.addElement(pnlFirstCmp);

for (var i:int = 1; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    var pnlOtherCmp:PnlOtherCmp = new PnlOtherCmp();
    this.addElement(pnlOtherCmp);
}
var pnlFooter:PnlFooter = new PnlFooter();
this.addElement(pnlFooter);
```

Now, problem is:
when I see my panel there are some spaces among the different panel that I added at runtime.

Where I'm wrong!?!?!?

[image: My undesiderate gap]

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:
My root node:

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%" 
     creationComplete="vbox1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
     verticalGap="0">
```

Creation complete:

```
protected function vbox1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    createPanel();
}
```

PnlFirstCmp (node root):

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%" 
     verticalGap="0">
```

PnlOtherCmp (node root):

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%" 
     verticalGap="0">
```

PnlFooter (node root):

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%" verticalGap="0">
```

If you want show other bit of codes, don't esitate ;)

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code. Show us the "root node", the `VBox` and where you're setting the gap to 0. Are "root node" and the `VBox` two components or the same thing? The code you've shown is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Could be the padding on the 'PnlFirstCmp' that you are using. try removing padddingTop and paddingbottom and see.

Comment: @Sunil D. / Zeus: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved.

The issue is: height="100%" in the root node!

I'm creating panel to rumtime and if I remove the height = "100%" Flex builds the panel for the exact dimension, otherwise it builds considering all available height, so add blank space at the footer of panel. In this way I've removed the blank space, so that OK. Thank you for your help Sunil D. & Zeus